# If trans type 2 is after 60 days of trans type 1

Tags: sql, oracle

Relative newbie here .. I'm trying to write a query where I have a list of transactions and I need to see if a different transaction type didn't happened after 60 days of it

```
E.g. A
Trans 1 : 1/1/18
Trans 2 : 1/11/17, 1/12/17, 2/1/18, 1/2/18, 1/3/18, 17/3/18
Did a trans 2 occurs within 60 days post trans 1 : Y
-->  I don't want to return this example
```

...

```
E.g. B
Trans 1 : 1/1/18
Trans 2 : 1/11/17, 1/12/17, 31/12/17, 17/3/18, 21/3/18
Did a trans 2 occurs within 60 days post trans 1 : N
--> I want to return this example
```

...

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT e.ID, sa.id                           ** LIST OF TRANSACTIONS #1* 
  FROM table1 e,
       table3 sa
  WHERE e.type_id   = 'ABC'
  AND sa.type_id    = 'PRE'
  ) S1,

  (SELECT sa.id, adj.date AS vdate              ** LIST OF TRANSACTIONS #2**
  FROM table4 sa,
    table5 adj
  WHERE sa.id = adj.id
  ) S2

WHERE S1.id = S2.id
and s2.vdate > S1.E_DT 

                ** ME TRYING TO COMPARE IF 1 date of TRANS 2 is after 60 days of TRANS 1** 

and s2.vdate < S1.E_DT + 60
and s2.vdate not between (S1.E_DT) and  (S1.E_DT + 60 )
```

Trans type 2 will have a large range of dates in the past and in the future of trans type 1.

From my googling I think I need a case option or possible a not exists ?

Can you please point me in the right direction ?

Thanks
Sarah

Comment: Which dbms are yoy using? (That query uses product specific features.)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, fix your code so it matches the description.  You have a nice description that mentions one table.  Then you have a mess of SQL code that mentions multiple tables.

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition  12.1.0.2.0

Comment: code simplified as much as I can ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of transactions #1 which didn't have a transaction #2 occur within 60 days, I'd use a NOT EXISTS:

```
select *
from
  (... your subquery ...) s1
where not exists
  (select 1 from  
      (...) s2
      where s1.id = s2.id
        and s2.vdate between s1.e_dt and s1.e_dt + 60);
```

If you want to look at all of the transactions #1 and see a flag showing whether they were followed by a transaction #2 within 60 days or not, I'd move the NOT EXISTS up into the SELECT clause and use a CASE.

```
select s1.*, 
    CASE WHEN not exists
          (select 1 from  
              (...) s2
              where s1.id = s2.id
                and s2.vdate between s1.e_dt and s1.e_dt + 60) 
         THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as no_trans2_in_60_days
from
  (...) s1
;
```

You could also do this as an outer join, but for your example, I don't think it would be worth the hassle.